# Этимология слов "молвить", "молва"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слов *молвить*, *молва*? Связаны ли они с украинским и белорусским *мова* («язык»)? Можно ли как-то объяснить отсутствие в русском (и, кстати, в белорусском) глагола, подобного украинскому *мовити* («говорить») или польскому *mówić* («говорить»)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С словаре Черных **все славянские варианты являются родственными** (Л в некоторых случаях выпадает), о.-с. основа  mъlva,  mъlviti.

Некоторые языковеды связывают эти слова с греческим "напев. мелодия", и.-е **корень mel,** тогда v - суффикс.

Также не исключено, что тот же корень присутствует в словах **"молить, молитва"**.